# Using Taylor expansion to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Use Taylor expansion to find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}$

I know that:

$\exp(2x) = 1 + (2x) + \frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+ O(x^3)$

$\ln(1-x) = 1-(-x) + (-x)^2 + O(x^3)$

$\sin(x) = x + O(x^3)$

$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + O(x^3)$

Substituting this in yields:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+2x+2x^2+O(x^3) -1 - x - x^2 + O(x^3) -x + O(x^3)}{-\frac{x^2}{2!} + O(x^3)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 + O(x^3)}{-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + O(x^3)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2[1+O(x)]}{x^2[-1/2+O(x)]} = -2$

---

EDIT: Progressing from $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+2x+\frac{5}{2}x^2+O(x^3)}{-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)}$ we have,

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 + 5/2x^2 +O(x^3)}{-1/2x^2 + O(x^3)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2(1/x^2 + 5/2 + O(x)}{x^2(-1/2 + O(x))} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-1/x^2 - 5/2 + O(x)}{1/2+O(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -1/x^2 - 5/2 + O(x) }{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1/2 + O(x)} = \frac{-\infty}{1/2} = -\infty$

Is this method rigorously correct?

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx+%5Crightarrow+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cexp%282x%29-%5Cln%281-x%29-%5Csin%28x%29%7D%7B%5Ccos%28x%29-1%7D) does not agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ is wrong

It should be $\displaystyle \ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$

Therefore, $$\frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}=\frac{1+2x+\frac{5}{2}x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac{-x^2}{2}+O(x^3)}$$

The last expression goes to $-\infty$

---

Further explanation of this last fact:

$$\frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}=\frac{1+2x+\frac{5}{2}x^2+O(x^3)}{\frac{-x^2}{2}+O(x^{\color{red}{4}})}=\frac{1+2x+O(x^2)}{\frac{-x^2}{2}(1+O(x^2))}$$

Since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+\color{red}{O(x^2)}}=1-\color{red}{O(x^2)}+O(\color{red}{O(x^2)})=1+O(x^2)$,

$$\frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}=\frac{\left(1+2x+O(x^2)\right)\left(1+O(x^2)\right)}{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$

Expanding the numerator, you get $\left(1+2x+O(x^2)\right)\left(1+O(x^2)\right)=1+2x+O(x^2)$

So : $\displaystyle \frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}=\frac{1+2x+O(x^2)}{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Hence, 
$$\frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}= \frac{-2}{x^2}-\frac{4}{x}+O(1)$$

But, at $0$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}=o(\frac{1}{x^2})$

Finally $$\frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}= \frac{-2}{x^2}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})+O(1)$$

The last quantity goes to $-\infty$

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly does this expression converge to $-\infty$? It is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1/x^2 + 2/x + 5/2 + O(x)}{-1/2!+ O(x)}$ but if we were to apply the algebraic limit theorem, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 2/x$ doesn't exist?

Comment: @user40333 before I can address your comment, do you know what asymptotic equivalence is ?

Comment: I don't think I've covered that... :(

Comment: @user40333 check my explanations. It's very rigorous, so tell me if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks! Your edit makes sense, I also thought about the question a bit more. I have edited my original post, is my argument also correct?

Comment: It is correct overall. Nevertheless, you forgot $2x$ in the numerator on the second line. More importantly, you mix $\lim$ and $O$,  which is not correct. The $O$ itself contains the "limit at $0$" statement (see how I wrote my answer). Tell me if something is unclear.

Comment: For the $2x$, I merged it into the $O(x^3)$, can I not do that?

Comment: No, it's not true. Intuituively, at $0$, $2x$ is way bigger than $x^3$ (in absolute value) . Rewrite the definition of $O(x^3) $ and see that your statement is not correct.