# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{2x} - \ln(1-x) - \sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}$ using Taylor Expansions

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

As a preface- a very similar question is here:

[Using Taylor expansion to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(2x)-\ln(1-x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800231/using-taylor-expansion-to-find-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-exp2x-ln1-x)

But, my actual question is, when we substitute the taylor expansions, how do we know what term to take them to?

For example, the OP in the other post expanded all his terms to $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$

Why didn't he use expansions up to $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ instead? How does one determine this? Surely it would work all the same at some terminal point, but knowing the minimum expansion could save much computational work, correct?

Comment: If it is just for the limit, the idea is to look first at the denominator. In this case $x^2$. If you want to see more (asymptotic behavior), higher order could be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if you expand to order one (the rest term of order two), then the denominator will be
$$
\cos x-1=(1+\mathcal O(x^2))-1=\mathcal O(x^2),
$$
and we cannot use this $\mathcal O(x^2)$ to calculate values. It just tells us something about orders. So, in this case, we should expand $\cos x$ to the order 2 at least, giving a denominator
$$
\cos x-1=(1-x^2/2+\mathcal O(x^3))-1=-x^2/2+\mathcal O(x^3).
$$
Now you can expand the numerator to match this.

In the general case it is a bit of trial and error, because it can be difficult to just look at the first expression and see what terms will cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing where to stop your expansion requires the knowledge of at least the beginning of the usual Taylor expansions (more precisely the one appearing in the denominator). For example here, it is a classical fact that $cos(x)-1$ does not have a $x$ term but begins at $x^2$, so here, going to $O(x^2)$ in the numerator won't be enough to know the limit, you have to push the expansion to $O(x^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in general you do not know how much to expand to without some foresight. The solution is to work backwards as follows.

Let "$[x]$" denote "$\{ y : |y| \le |x| \}$", where $y$ is quantified over whatever domain you like such as complex numbers.

Let "$f$ to precision $r$" mean an approximation $g$ of $f$ such that $g \in f \cdot (1+[r])$.

- Any of $\{ f \times g , f \div g \}$ to precision $r$ requires $f,g$ to precision $r$.
- Any of $\{ f + g , f - g \}$ to precision $r$ requires $f,g$ to sufficiently high precision such that the result has precision $r$. This is in practice not hard to do because we just compute them with the precision we want and only if the result has cancellation do we need to redo the computation with higher precision, and unless everything cancelled we would already know how high we need to go.

These rules suffice to deal with most functions, but not all. In general some structure is necessary since $f(x)$ cannot be computed to arbitrary precision at discontinuities of $f$ without having $x$ to infinite precision.

Comment: Hmm yes, I know some of these words

Comment: @elbarto: What do you mean by "some of these words"? Anyway this is the only way available if you cannot guess anything about the asymptotic expansion in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop until you get a nonzero term.

At the numerator:

Coefficient of $x^0$: $$1,$$ you are done.

At the denominator:

Coefficient of $x^0$: $$1-1=0.$$

Coefficient of $x^1$: no term.

Coefficient of $x^2$: $$-\frac12,$$ you're done.

Then the limit is that of $\frac{1}{-\frac{x^2}2}$.

Comment: This is not a very interesting example.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator $\to 1,$ the denominator $\to 0$ through negative values, so the limit is $-\infty.$

Comment: This would fit better at the linked question. It doesn't address the question how we know how far to take the expansion.